# how can disable the checkbox programmatically in a bootstrapTable?

Tags: bootstrap-table

I need to disable the checkboxes of the rows that were selected to avoid being selected for a second time, use custom

```
function stateCheckBoxFormatter(value, row, index) {
       logic for disable or not
       return {
                disabled: true,
                checked: false
            };
}
```

but it only works when the table starts or it refreshes, and what I occupy is to deactivate without needing to refresh.
something like that
let _data = $table.bootstrapTable('getSelections');
logic to disable the checkboxes in the array. Thanks

Comment: Submit a jsfiddle showing your problem.

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/